# webpack externals with wildcard

Tags: webpack

How can I instruct webpack to exlude all d3-modules?

```
// does not work
externals: {
        "d3-*": "d3"
    }
```

So if app imports d3-submodule, then webpack should not include this submodule because I have already included d3.js.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use regular expressions (see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#regex).

```
// This might work
externals: /^d3-.*/
```

Comment: Moreover, it is possible to combine regexp with object:

externals: [
  {
    'mobx': 'mobx',
  },
  /^d3-.*/
]